# Error in function imshow

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to make a custom object detector (chairs) using the HOG+SVM method. My plan of action is to:

- Loop through the images in my folder
- Read and resize them
- Convert them to vectors using the hog.compute() function
- And then store them into a data file

If all goes well, my SVM classifier will handle the rest.

Then ideally, it will be able to identify the chairs that are displayed through my webcam.

Here's the code I'm trying to use (only the initial bit):

```
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np

def loadimg():

    for i in range(0,19):
        image = cv2.imread(str(i))
        cv2.imshow("img",image)
        (winW, winH) = (500, 500)
        r = 128.0 / image.shape[1]
        dim = (128, int(image.shape[0] * r))
        img = cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
    return img

def hoggify(img):
    imeg = hog.compute(img)
    return imeg

for fn in os.listdir('/Users/munirmalik/cvprojek/cod'):
loadimg()
hoggify(imeg)
np.savetxt('data.txt')
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
cv2.error: /Users/munirmalik/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:304: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function imshow
```

I've googled the error and it says that imread() isn't reading my image, which I'm assuming has to do with my for loop in the loadimg() function.

Can someone please help me out? Also if you can think of a better way to go about doing this, please do let me know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the bug in your code

```
   for i in range(0,19):
        image = cv2.imread(str(i))
```

This translates to `cv2.imread("0")`. The `cv2.imread()` functon needs to be passed an image address like "path/to/image.jpg". I'm not sure how your images are arranged in the file structure, but the argument to `cv2.imread()` should end in a file extension like JPG, PNG, etc

As per OP's comment, the code should be changed to:

```
   for i in range(0,19):
        image = cv2.imread(r"/Users/munirmalik/cvprojek/cod/chairs/" + str(i)+ ".jpg")
```

Comment: So how would I include the path and the string "i" in that function?
image = cv2.imread("/Users/munirmalik/cvprojek/cod/chairs/"str(i)) gives me an error

Comment: @MunirMalik I've edited the answer. Are your images named 0.jpg, 1.jpg, 2. jpg, etc?